# permutation cipher definition unclear

Tags: encryption, permutation

I have an assignment to decode a permutation cipher based on a key. But on the internet I found only ONE website talking about it. Things are not very clear.

I understand that I have to reorder the key characters alphabetically and then permute the columns accordingly, but it doesn't seem to make sense when I decode. Here it is. Maybe I got the wrong definition of it ...

```
IRUHA AIFAI SHIEI PLDEY EENIT 
SIOFH OCPED OASLS EREUC RSMHL 
RESOT SROPI RDFSN DIOVB IRAYA 
MNBKM OAIRR OANAS REDIC YNSSO 
ELNYG HDMSE ODHCO MHAND FOCNI 
IMBIE LCUPI APEOE IIINP APPRA 
RKPSS EVNBS SIRHH ODOVM AICSA 
ALTOM NHTON AMOFP RYHVS LNRCN 
NCIHP ATTTT EENED HDNLI AOTTO 
UHCTL SPITM CTAAT SENVN ETOTR 
DHESV INPON TTATN YACRL DTOSL 
ETHDH AANSL RMERI GMIOP SIECE 
SEOLS CCTPI IRETE ETEYE DCTAH 
PEEAI OTFOE TCTLS EIOAR CSCEU 
GDAFU OHLGI RAYAR NEERO PNSUR 
VETEI FAIIE YCIOD RNTHH RHTIN 
TLECN CHBTI ELLAE EEEES SGNIU 
SNCEF HRETL LTHUS EDBSF OOSAR 
ASNHO YGHCO UUATU ORIRS YNSTP 
GRGAD NPSIR RDMSY GBNHP AIAMN 
ETPRY IIEIL IEUNA ANTRU NTAMS 
EONEY ER
```

with the following key:

```
key=water
```

Here is what I tried:

```
WATER
12345
AERTW
24531

RHAUI
IFHOS
EOTSR
NKMBM
```

Comment: does this helps ?https://www.nku.edu/~christensen/1402%20permutation%20ciphers.pdf

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: Unless there are words with e.g. 4 T's and one vowel in there something is wrong with just permutation. Permutation ciphers reorder the characters in a block. This looks more like combined permutation and substitution or even just substitution.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, it is clear that there is problem. Consider, however, this for your TTTT; buTTaTToo.